# How to fix Interop.SHDocVw.dll problem on windows 10?

Tags: vb.net

I am working with an application developed for windows 7 and i m trying to run it on windows 10. This software use both of  WatiN.Core.dll and Interop.SHDocVw.dll. The Watin Dll was already in the references of program and the other one I added it after getting an error while debugging the program. The text of exception is:

> "Impossible to load the file or the assembly Interop.SHDocVw, Version
>   = 1.1.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken = "...." or one of their dependencies. The specified file not found "

I am using windows 10 and Microsoft visual studio 2017.

I have put the properties  "Incorporate intro type" of Interop.SHDocVw.dll  to False, but still i get the same error.

What else can i do to fix this issue ?

Comment: You can try turning on assembly resolution logging and see if the logs tell you anything useful.  Look up "fuslogvw" on the intertubes for more info.